# Is a "sync"-function also sync, if it's run in a promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I just wanted to know if a 'sync'-function, run in a promise, is synchronous (and slows down other stuff) or async, like I think?

Example:

```
function getFileContent(filepath){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFileSync("asd.txt"));
    });
}
```

Comment: If you are going to use a function that is explicitly synchronous, there is no reason to wrap it in a promise (otherwise you should use the async version). You also don't `return` anything, so the contents of the file are never used. You also never call `resolve` or `reject` here, so the promise you do return never completes.

Comment: A promise is not an alternative to `setTimeout`. It doesn't make synchronous code run "in the future", it invokes its callback *immediately*, and blocks the **current** callstack. `fs.readFileSync(...)` and `new Promise(() => fs.readFileSync())` behave **identically**, and both block the current thread of execution. Neither is "async".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functions are synchronous. Period.

What can be asynchronous is an (abstract) process/workflow.

When someone says a function is "async" what they actually mean is that the result will be available some time later. The result is wrapped in a Promise, which is a handle to await. But the process may still be synchronous. Have a look at this example:

```js
function foo() {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        console.log(1);
        console.log(2);
        res();
    });
};

function test() {
    foo();
    console.log(3);
};
```

and the output is always the same:

```js
> test();
1
2
3
```

which means that each function was called one after another in a synchronous manner. And indeed if you update `foo` function to:

```js
function foo() {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        while (true) {}
        res();
    });
};
```

you will notice that `console.log(3)` **never** runs. And so our `foo` blocks forever!

Now have a look at this example:

```js
function test() {
    Promise.resolve().then(function() {
        console.log(1);
        console.log(2);
    });
    console.log(3);
};
```

and note the different result: `3 1 2`. **All those functions are synchronous**, so why the order is different? Because `.then()` postpones the execution to some later time.

All in all: sync/async is not really a property of a function, but rather a property of a workflow. And in your case it is synchronous.

**Side note:** this gets more complicated when exceptions are involved. Let's modify the `foo` function from the first example:

```js
function foo() {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        throw 'myException';
    });
};

function test() {
    foo();
    console.log(3);
};
```

and call `test()`. Oh, wow, now `3` is first (someone may think that it should not be executed at all!!!) and the uncaught exception `myException` second. Why? Because JavaScript engine postpones exception handling. Don't ask me why, I have no idea, but I'm sure there is a reason for this... like for everything. ;)

**Conclusion:** Promises don't make things automatically asynchronous and always `await` or use `.then()` with a function that returns a Promise (unless you're a ninja).

Comment: Finally, this is the correct answer. Placing a blocking function inside a promise doesn't make it non-blocking, as every other answer (so far) has implied. The thread of execution will *immediately* block on `fs.readFileSync`, regardless of how many promises or callbacks you wrap that function in. Promises invoke their callback functions immediately, they cannot turn a synchronous function asynchronous. You would need `setTimeout` for that.

Comment: @meagar with the exception of... exceptions (see the update). Yeah, JavaScript...

Comment: Unhandled promise rejections are their own thing, and the behavior will change in the future to simply terminating the whole process (in Node). The problem is you don't have a `catch`, meaning your code is incorrect: Promise chains are *required* to eventually catch rejections, or your code is incorrect and invoking undefined behavior. If you catch your exception, the code goes "back" to being synchronous and consistent.

Comment: @meagar Catching an exception is not mandatory. Exception propagation is well defined and not an *undefined behaviour*. There is no such thing in JavaScript. The behaviour is consistent. It is just not intuitive (like half of JavaScript anyway).

Comment: I'm not talking about uncaught exceptions, I'm talking about uncaught rejections.

Comment: Whatever, both are well defined.

Comment: *JavaScript engine postpones exception handling* - that's not true. Exception thrown in an executor sets a promise state to *rejected* and rejection is handled asynchronously. If there isn't a rejection handler (and this can only be checked after current code is run) then an unhandled error is logged. So exception handling in promises is not *postponed* it's just performed in an async way.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I get the point that it was just an example

The thing about Promise constructors is that they execute their `executor` immediately.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

> A function that is passed with the arguments resolve and reject. The executor function is executed immediately by the Promise implementation, passing resolve and reject functions (the executor is called before the Promise constructor even returns the created object).

Which means, in your example `fs.readFileSync` is executed immediately and (edited) blocks the rest of your code from running (see comment)

Comment: This is the closest answer to correct, but your final paragraph is sitll wrong. `fs.readFileSync` is invoked immediately, in the same callstack, and blocks execution. Given this code... `new Promise(() => console.log('first')); console.log('second')`, the output is `first\nsecond`, not `second\nfirst`. As you said, the executor is invoked *immediately*, and if the executor blocks, the thread blocks. Code being in a callback doesn't make it non-blocking.

Answer (score 0):

There are two interpretations of "async" here, and the answer to both is "no", promises don't make `fs.readFileSync` *any* kind of asynchronous.

The first interpretation would be, does `new Promise` behave like `setTimeout`. It doesn't.

Promises invoke their callback functions **immediately**. They do not defer execution, meaning a blocking function wrapped in a promise will *still* block the main thread of execution.

There is **no difference** between these implementations:

```
function getFileContent(filepath){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFileSync("asd.txt"));
    });
}
```

and

```
function getFileContent(filepath){
  fs.readFileSync("asd.txt"));
}
```

Both of these call `fs.readFileSync` immediately on the current callstack.

To make the function "async" (as in, to defer its execution) you need to use `setTimeout`. You can wrap *that* in a promise, but you're adding no functional change by doing so, only syntactic sugar.

The second interpretation of "async" could be whether you can prevent your program from blocking on a call to `fs.readFileSync`. That is impossible, `fs.readFileSync` will always be blocking, and if it takes 10 seconds to read that file, your program will *always* be unresponsive for 10 seconds, no matter how you try to defer the execution with promises or `setTimeout`.

The only fix is to use `fs.readFile`, not `fs.readFileSync`. This is why the non-sync versions of these functions exist: It is impossible to make `fs.readFileSync` *not* break your program on large/slow reads.

Comment: These implementations unfortunately are not equivalent due to different exception handling. See my answer.

Comment: @freakish They *are* identical, assuming no exceptions are raised. If the promise can be rejected, then the promise needs a `catch` or it is undefined behavior.